# Absolute element moving away from image

Tags: css

Can I somehow make the absolute element stay at the same position all the time even when the parent(relative) image is adjusting its size to screen? At the moment I am using `px` to use position of elements, its fine on huge screen, but whenever the image gets smaller the absolute elements wont stick to the same position. Also I tried using `<img></img>` and put elements inside it and make the img as relative, but I think these tags dont work.

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container > p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/surfing/surfing_PNG9721.png" class="img">
  <p>Im absolute
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: use percentage value instead of pixel

Comment: You want the text to seem like its on the surf board? Or you want it to appear right after it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use percentage and for font-size use clamp()

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container > p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 22%;
  bottom: 48%;
  color : white;
  font-size: clamp(5px,2vw,3rem);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/surfing/surfing_PNG9721.png" class="img">
  <p>Im absolute
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "position: relative;" of the container. Your p tag is absolute respect the container because of that. Removing relative in container, the absolute is refered to the document.

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.container > p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
  bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/surfing/surfing_PNG9721.png" class="img">
  <p>Im absolute
  </p>
</div>
```